# Unknown column XXXX in field_list

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

**OK, here's a weird issue :**

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'alias' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `alias`, `url`, `domains`, `progress`,
>   `total`, `email`) 
>   VALUES 
>   (80511, 'Some Alias', 'somedomains.com',
>   'xxxxxx', 0, 199, 'some@gmail.com')

I've been using a specific database table, which I've been populated through a model script.
After I added another column (let's say `alias`), the function doesn't work anymore and displays the above error.

---

**And the Database population code :**

```
function createNew($proj)
{
    $data = array(
        'id' => $proj['id'],
        'alias' => $proj['alias'],
        'url' => $proj['url'],
        'domains' => $proj['domains'],
        'progress' => $proj['progress'],
        'total' => $proj['total'],
        'email' => $proj['email']
        );

    $this->db->insert('projects',$data);
}
```

---

The weirdest thing of all is that when I manually execute the **exact** same query (e.g. using the SQL via phpMyAdmin), it works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have correct database selcted?

Comment: @user35443 Yes. In any case, it was working 100% just before I added that extra column... :S

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the table in phpmyadmin? try to insert a row directly in phpmyadmin and compare the generated query with yours.

Comment: use ``'`alias`' => $proj['alias']``

Comment: I think @Dr.Kameleon is looking at the wrong database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `query` method?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO projects (id, alias, url, domains, progress, total, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$this->db->query($sql,$proj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since alias is a keyword in Sql so just use '`alias`' when you want to insert data to the table.

'`alias`' => $proj['alias']